# THREE.js - Updating BufferGeometry position twice, causes my FPS to suffer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an array of TubeBufferGeometrys that im making animate to look as if they're growing out in length. When the animation runs the first time, it works really smoothly at 60fps. But once i set the geometrys position attributes back to zero, the FPS drop to 30.

Ive isolated my animation to run and then rerun once it finished with only the below changing. Heres the basics of my code:

**Animation control view**

```
stop() {
  this.play = false;

  // Start it again
  setTimeout(() => {
    let i = this.tubeCount;
    while (i--) {
      this.tubes[i].lastSegmentSet = 0;
      this.tubes[i].updateToPercent(0);
    }

    this.elapsedTime = 0;
    this.startTime = Date.now();

    this.play = true;
  }, 2000)
}

update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  // ..render stuff + composer that ive disabled without effect


  if (this.play) {
    let percent = (Date.now() - this.startTime) / ANIMATE_DURATION;
    if (percent >= 1) {
      this.stop();
    }

    let i = this.lineCount;
    while (i--) {
      this.tubes[i].updateToPercent(percent);
    }
  }
}
```

**Tube class (The main animation code)**

```
constructor() {
  //..other stuff

  this.lastSegmentSet = 0;
}

// I first build the paths, then store the position data to use later to animate to. Then i set all the position data to zero
storeVerticies() {
  this.positions = this.tube.geometry.attributes.position.array.slice(0);

  const length = this.tube.geometry.attributes.position.array.length;
  this.tube.geometry.attributes.position.array = new Float32Array(length);
}

setSegment(segment) {
  this.setSegmentTo(segment, segment);
}

setSegmentTo(segment, target) {
  let position = this.tube.geometry.attributes.position.array;
  let startPoint = segment * JOINT_DATA_LENGTH; //JOINT_DATA_LENGTH is the number of values in the buffer geometry to update a segment
  let targetPoint = target * JOINT_DATA_LENGTH;

  let n = JOINT_DATA_LENGTH;
  while (n--) {
    position[startPoint + n] = this.positions[targetPoint + n];
  }
}

updateToPercent(percent) {
  let endSegment = Math.floor(percent * this.segmentCount);
  while (this.lastSegmentSet <= endSegment) {
    this.setSegment(this.lastSegmentSet++);
  }

  let n = this.lastSegmentSet;
  while (n <= this.segmentCount + 1) {
    this.setSegmentTo(n++, this.lastSegmentSet);
  }

  this.tube.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Will put bounty when possible

Comment: Are you calling requestAnimationFrame somewhere else too?

Comment: @2pha Im not at all :/ I'll try get a JSFiddle up tonight / tomorrow.